# Airflow, Folder sensor and task trigger

Tags: file, directory, triggers, airflow, sensors

Hi guys please I am having a little trouble creating a file sensor that can do the following
Sense documents in a folder
Returns a print statement if any file in that folder is modified i.e. created , deleted e.t.c
Triggers a particular task to run if a file is added to that folder. (e.g. Task 1 runs immediately when triggered.)
This is my present code. It can sense if a file exist,  but doesn’t returns fail or print statement if the file doesn’t not exist. Thank you

```py
default_args = {
    "depends_on_past" : False,
    "start_date"      : airflow.utils.dates.days_ago( 1 ),
    "retries"         : 1,
    "retry_delay"     : datetime.timedelta( hours= 5 ),
}

with airflow.DAG("file_sensor_test_v3", 
                 default_args=default_args, 
                 schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *") as dag:

    start_task  = DummyOperator(  task_id= "start" )
    stop_task   = DummyOperator(  task_id= "stop"  )
    sensor_task = FileSensor( task_id= "my_file_sensor_task", poke_interval= 30, fs_conn_id= 'fs_default', filepath= '/path/to/file/' )

start_task >> sensor_task >> stop_task
```

(Code was modified earlier from stack overflow)

Comment: FileSensor can only tell you if particular file(s) exists in a directory or not, or if a particular directory contains files or not. It alone cannot monitor all changes in the folder and act differently on each change.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I later figured that out so I used python and then called the function in airflow. Thanks

Comment: great! You can answer to your questions with your solution to help others with the same problem.